# Postgres jsonb query missing index?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-indexes, jsonb

We have the following json documents stored in our PG table (identities) in a jsonb column 'data':

```
{
    "email": {
        "main": "mainemail@email.com",
        "prefix": "aliasPrefix",
        "prettyEmails": ["stuff1", "stuff2"]
    },
    ...
}
```

I have the following index set up on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_identities_email_main
  ON identities
  USING gin
  ((data -> 'email->main'::text) jsonb_path_ops);
```

What am I missing that is preventing the following query from hitting that index?? It does a full seq scan on the table... We have tens of millions of rows, so this query is hanging for 15+ minutes...

```
SELECT * FROM identities WHERE data->'email'->>'main'='mainemail@email.com';
```

Comment: I've also tried

    `data @> '{"email": {"main": "mainemail@email.com"}}'`

But that not only misses the index as well, it isn't really the query I want anyways because of the other properties on the email object.

Comment: Can you share the query plan generated (`EXPLAIN ...`)?

Comment: Sure thing: `"  Filter: (((data -> 'email'::text) ->> 'main'::text) = 'testemail@email.com'::text)"`

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**JSONB**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) data type for your **`data`** column, in order to index  **ALL** **`"email"`** entry values you need to create following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ident_data_email_gin_idx ON identities USING gin ((data -> 'email'));
```

Also keep in mind that for `JSONB` you need to use appropriate list of operators;

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with the @>,
>   ?, ?& and ?| operators

Following queries will hit this index:

```
SELECT * FROM identities
WHERE data->'email' @> '{"main": "mainemail@email.com"}'
-- OR
SELECT * FROM identities
WHERE data->'email' @> '{"prefix": "aliasPrefix"}'
```

If you need to search against array elements `"stuff1"` or `"stuff2"`, index above will not work , you need to explicitly add expression index on `"prettyEmails"` array element values in order to make query work faster.

```
CREATE INDEX ident_data_prettyemails_gin_idx ON identities USING gin ((data -> 'email' -> 'prettyEmails'));
```

This query will hit the index:

```
SELECT * FROM identities
WHERE data->'email' @> '{"prettyEmails":["stuff1"]}'
```